# Error calling external WCF service from class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, class, service

I'm trying to call a external wcf service from my application I've added the reference and I'm able to reference the methods within the WCF Service but when I run it in debug I get the following error,

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ExternalServive.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

The below wcf service is just a simple upload image and save to a local folder, I've checked through other threads but I've got a little bit confused.

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://voiceitonline.co.uk.ukwsp3.com/Service1.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="ExternalServive.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

The wcf service is located in a class library, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `ExternalServive.IService1` is correct? It looks like a spelling mistake ExternalServi**v**e.IService1

Comment: @rene yes its correct, I mis-typed it that's all

Comment: @rene I removed it and added it again with the correct spelling I now get a wiggly blue line under the bindingConfiguration

Comment: do you have binding named BasicHttpBinding_IService1 under basicHttpBinding? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rene the blue wiggly line has gone now, I done a right click update configuration, still get the error mentioned above though

Comment: The config is in your web.config. right?

Comment: @rene when I added the reference it got put into my app.config automatically not the web config

Comment: and you are running this from a windows app, not a web app?

Comment: @rene running from a web app, we have a class library included in the solution, and we make a call to that class library when the user performs an action from the web application and  that's where we call/try the external wcf service

Comment: Then the wcf config should be in your web.config. Move everything under serviceModel from your app.config to your web.config

Comment: @rene its working thanks, but Inside my class library I moved the settings from the app.config into my web.config and run the application and error still existed, yet If i add the settings in to my Web Application Config as well it worked I'm not sure why I need to add the reference in to places

Comment: The WCF settings can only exist for the process (one reason being that it uses processwide resources like ports) and that dictates that it's settings should go in the Configuration file that is used for the process setup (or technically the appdomain setup). In cases where my WCF stuff is in another project I normally have some postbuild step to merge config files so I can maintain one source.

Comment: @rene do you have an example/tutorial of "In cases where my WCF stuff is in another project I normally have some postbuild step to merge config files so I can maintain one source"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165412.aspx and tools like these http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7406/XmlConfigMerge-Merge-config-file-settings but I've also run my own by writing a custom build task that fiddles with xmlreaders and xmlwriters.